# 'str' object has no attribute 'attname'

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to display a link to the next and previous object according the title field using  get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD. Django 1.6 is throwing me this error.

Error during template rendering
`'str' object has no attribute 'attname'`

Error occurs here in template.

`{% with next_lesson=lesson.get_next_by_title %}`

And here in my models.

`return self._get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD('title', is_next=True)`

Here is my model.

```
class LessonManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self):
        return super(LessonManager, self).filter(active=True)

class Lesson(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=65)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    objects = LessonManager()

    def __unicode__(self, ):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('lesson', args=[str(self.slug)])

    def get_next_by_title(self):
        try:
            return self._get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD('title', is_next=True)
        except Lesson.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_previous_by_title(self):
        try:
            return self._get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD(order='title', is_next=False)
        except Lesson.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

And here is my template.

```
<a class="col-md-6" href="{{ lesson.get_previous_by_title.get_absolute_url }}" title="{% trans "View previous post" %}">&laquo; {{ lesson.get_previous_by_title.title }}</a>
<a class="col-md-6" href="{{ lesson.get_next_by_title.get_absolute_url }}" title="{% trans "View previous post" %}">&laquo; {{ lesson.get_next_by_title.title }}</a>
```

Here is the full traceback as requested.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: /tutorials/lesson/lesson-name/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog',
 'ckeditor',
 'tutorials')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
Template error:
In template C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\static\templates\tutorials\lesson.html, error at line 22
   'str' object has no attribute 'attname'
   12 :     {% endif %}


   13 :     {% if lesson.get_next_by_timestamp %}


   14 :         <a class="right" href="{{ lesson.get_next_post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ lesson.get_next_post.title|truncatewords:'4' }} &raquo;</a>


   15 :     {% endif %}


   16 : 


   17 :     <div class='clearfix'></div>


   18 : 


   19 :     <h2>{{ lesson.title|upper }}</h2>


   20 :     <p>{{ lesson.content|safe }}</p>


   21 :     


   22 :     <a class="col-md-6" href=" {{ lesson.get_previous_by_title.get_absolute_url }} " title="{% trans "View previous post" %}">&laquo; {{ lesson.get_previous_by_title.title }}</a>


   23 :   <a class="col-md-6" href="{{ lesson.get_next_by_title.get_absolute_url }}" title="{% trans "View previous post" %}">&laquo; {{ lesson.get_next_by_title.title }}</a>


   24 : 


   25 : {% endblock %}

Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\src\tutorials\views.py" in single_lesson
  13.     return render_to_response('tutorials/lesson.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts\__init__.py" in render_to_response
  29.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  169.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render
  88.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  585.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  735.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  789.                             current = current()
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\src\tutorials\models.py" in get_previous_by_title
  64.             return self._get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD('title', is_next=False)
File "C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\sg\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD
  708.         param = force_text(getattr(self, field.attname))

Exception Type: AttributeError at /tutorials/lesson/setting-up-your-django-blog-application/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'attname'
```

Comment: You need to show the full traceback.

Comment: Added full traceback and updated my template to simplify but still getting the error. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD` isn't supposed to be something you call yourself.

The main problem you're having is that it is expecting a Field object, not a string, hence the error. This is because the method is actually used as part of a curried function that is created by the field class itself, which in turn is called by the model metaclass when the model is first imported.

The currying creates the actual `get_next_by_foo` and `get_previous_by_foo` methods. In fact, these are only created for Date and Datetime fields.

Note that the uncurried method name begins with an underscore, which - with the exception of `Model._meta` - is a good sign that you're not supposed to be using it in your own code.

Comment: Thank you for your expert advice. I was told a custom method could work, now I don't feel so bad I couldn't get it!